# Proof for existence of LU decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The LU Decomposition for a matrix exists if and only if it can be reduced to reduced row echelon form without any row interchanges.

How to prove this theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write each step of Gaussian elimination as multiplication by a matrix. These are called elementary matrices. Then the algorithm gets you $U=E_n E_{n-1} \dots E_1 A$. (I write it this way because $E_1$ is the first step.) Then you know that each of the $E_i$ are invertible (why?) so you can define $L=E_1^{-1} E_{2}^{-1} \dots E_n^{-1}$. That tells you that reduction without row interchanges implies the existence of an LU decomposition.

For the other direction, the calculation above and the special shape of elementary matrices shows you how to read off the steps of Gaussian elimination from the entries of $L$. Since then the result is $U$ which is upper triangular, you are done.